# Parameterizing a cycloid, and finding the arclength

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to:

**1)** Parameterize a curve of a cycloid passing through the origin, of a disk of radius $1$,

**2)** Calculate the arc-length of one cycloid corresponding to one full rotation of the disk.

---

Let's start with 1), so we want $\alpha: \Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$, and starting at the origin means starting at the bottom of the disk, and moving clockwise. '$\alpha(t)=(\,\cos(t +\frac{\pi}2),\, -\sin(t+\frac\pi2)\,)$', this just gives a circle from the correct starting point and in the correct direction, but now we want to increase $x(t)$ linearly. So then we just add $+t$ I suppose:

$$\alpha(t)=(\,t+\cos(t +\frac{\pi}2),\, -\sin(t+\frac\pi2)\,)$$

2) I guess I want to calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\alpha'(t)|\,\mathrm{d}t$ where $$|\alpha'(t)|=\sqrt{\left(1-\sin(t+\frac\pi2)\right)^2+\left(-\cos(t+\frac\pi2)\right)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{1-\sin(t+\frac\pi2)+\sin^2(t+\frac\pi2)+\cos^2(t+\frac\pi2)}=\sqrt{2-\sin(t+\frac\pi2)}$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{2-\sin(t+\frac\pi2)} \,\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=\left[\frac23\left(2-\sin(t+\frac\pi2)\right)^{\frac32}\times\frac{1}{-\cos(t+\frac\pi2)}\right]_0^{2\pi}$$
$$=\frac23\left(2-\sin(2\pi+\frac\pi2)\right)^{\frac32}\times\frac{1}{-\cos(2\pi+\frac\pi2)}-\frac23\left(2-\sin(\frac\pi2)\right)^{\frac32}\times\frac{1}{-\cos(\frac\pi2)}$$
$$=\frac23\times\frac10-\frac23\times\frac10$$

---

Well something has definitely gone wrong. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You can't "invert" the chain rule like you did in the step right after the integral. The counterpart of the chain rule for differentiation is integration by substitution.

Comment: @joriki Ahhh my mistake again, it's been so long since Calculus classes. I'll fix that now

Edit: I have to travel for 2 hours, so I'll fix it when I get home

Comment: $\sin \left( \theta + \frac{\pi}{2} \right)  = \cos \theta \text{ and } \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos \theta}{2}}$ are useful here.

Answer (score 1):

One arch of the cycloid for disk of radius $r$ can be parametrized by:

$x = r(t-\sin{t}) \space , \space  y = r(1-\cos{t})$

where $0 \leq t \leq 2\pi $ and $\frac{dx}{dt} = r(1-\cos{t})$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = r \sin{t}$

Arc length $S$ for one arch:

$S = \int\limits_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{ \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2} dt$

$ = \int\limits_0^{2\pi} r \sqrt{2 -2\cos{t}} \space dt = \int\limits_0^{2\pi} 2 r \sin{\frac{t}{2}} \space dt $

$ = 8r $

For your case $ r = 1$ and thus $S = 8$.